# Listview on a listview in UWP- Should I reconsider my design or are there special things to consider?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, win-universal-app

I'm using a library a coworker built to handle the menu options that should be appearing on a screen of our app. The menu actions can be divided into subcategories. As such, he has a list of objects that provide the category, and on each of these objects is another list that provides the items on that category.

So basically I have a ListView (for the list of main options), and in that listview's item template I define another listview that is bound to the list of items.

The problems I am encountering are this-

1) I do NOT want the parent listview to be enabled. What happens currently is when I hover over an item, the item lights up as selectable, but so does the entire list (since it itself is an item in a listview). This almost leads me to believe that there's a different control that I should be using for this purpose, but I don't know enough to really say.

2) For some reason, I get build errors when I attempt to bind a click event from my viewmodel onto the inner list. It works fine when it's on the outer list, but I get "object not set to a reference" build errors when it's on the inner one. I'm trying to use {x:Bind ...} because from my understanding that should always map from the page level and work consistently no matter where in the xaml I use it, but that clearly doesn't seem to be the case.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the related xaml. The click event is on the outer list at the moment. I tried using an ItemsControl for the outer list but ended up getting non-descriptive runtime errors (it breaks out of the debugger and gives me an unhandled exception with a catastrophic failure message)

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MenuGroups}"  ItemClick="{x:Bind ViewModel.ClickDay}" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Margin="5, 0, 0, 10">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderName}" Foreground="Gray" />
                    </Border>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ActionList}">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                    <SymbolIcon Grid.Column="1" Symbol="Forward" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Where "MenuGroups" is a list of Object{string:HeaderName, List:ActionList}, and where MenuOptions is just an object holding a string for its name. At least those are the necessary pieces to reproduce this.

Comment: What code do you have that shows the problem? Is this basically a list of categories that each contain a list of selectable items for each category?

Comment: I've updated the question with a code sample. Let me know if that helps you understand my problem any better, thanks =)